# PHP find date after six months added to now() function

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a subscription system in my website. When the users subscribe, their start date and time is added using the `now()` function. I also need to calculate the date and time six months from now and store it in database. How can I do it?

Comment: I tried that solution but didn't work but the below answer works fine @Glavić

Comment: `DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` returns `2015-06-01`, and `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` returns `2015-06-01 08:44:37`. So solution `DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))` doesn't make any sense. If you have `DATETIME` field use first solution, if you have `DATE` field use second solution. Btw, why do you store `Y-m-d` to `DATETIME` column? Can you show your table schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))
```

can be used directly in your query and will do the job:

```
INSERT INTO table (datenow,dateplus6m) VALUES (NOW(), DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)));
```

---

*Explanation from the docs:*

**DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)**

These functions perform date arithmetic. The date argument specifies the starting date or datetime value. expr is an expression specifying the interval value to be added or subtracted from the starting date. expr is a string; it may start with a “-” for negative intervals. unit is a keyword indicating the units in which the expression should be interpreted.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but When I use only NOW(), the values are stored in the database. But when I use the DATE_ADD function, none of the values are stored in the database.

Comment: Is the other column a datetime column?

Comment: yes both are datetime columns. I have one username column and two datetime column.

Comment: Sorry, now!.... @Anbu369

Comment: No. Still no entry in database. Here is the code I am using `mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users (fb_id, fb_name, pro_start, pro_end) VALUES ('$fbid2', '$fbname2', NOW(), DATE_ADD (CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH))");`

Comment: Made another edit, it updates for me like this. @Anbu369

Answer (score 2):

The [`date_add`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function is what you're looking for:

```
INSERT INTO users
(username, registration_date, six_months_date)
VALUES ('someone', NOW(), DATE_ADD (NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 months", time()));
echo $newDate;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2015-06-01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date function for adding months in php .
Suppose $date contains current date,$date1 contains current date + 6 months

Here is the code

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
echo $date;
$date1=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("6 months"));
echo $date1;
```

Here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for other options

Hope this helps!